# Yesod/Persistent not closing DB connections

Tags: postgresql, haskell, yesod, haskell-persistent

I have a web app that uses Yesod and Persistent.  I'm using the default scaffolded `Foundation.hs` and `Application.hs`.  I've written a function which processes a local JSON file, and then inserts a row into several tables for each item in the JSON file.  So it is going to be performing 1000+ inserts in all.

Running the function in GHCI, it successfully saves some rows, and then errors with:

`libpq: failed (FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already)`

Using the postgres query:

`select *
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'mydb-name'`

I can see that there are 100 idle connections that have been created by my app and not closed.  I then need to kill these connections to be able to do anything.

Shouldn't persistent be closing these connections as the `INSERT` queries complete?  What do I need to do differently?

Comment: This would in fact be a bug, but I haven't seen this behavior in any of the web apps I maintain. Have you potentially modified the scaffolding in some way? How are you running these functions from GHCi? Is it possible that it's the GHCi session itself holding onto the connections?

Comment: Huh - you were right, it is something to do with GHCi.  I made an executable that just called the function I was testing, and the problem disappeared.  Just tried it again in GHCi and it still breaks there.  Does this sound like a bug with GHCi? Worth reporting it anywhere?

Comment: It depends on how you're calling it from GHCi, so I can't really tell.